# AASM: sort records according to aasm_column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aasm

```
aasm_column :status  

aasm do
  state :unpaid, :initial => true
  state :paid
  state :refund
  state :closed
  state :cancelled
...
```

These are the states in a model, and I need to sort the records according to the states of aasm_column. For example, I have five records and they all have different states. Now, I need to get all the records and they should be sorted as the one with 'unpaid' at first, then 'paid' at second, etc. If there has an elegant way to achieve it.

Comment: Is sorting via ruby OK or are you requiring that the database should do the sorting?

Comment: Maybe, I prefer **aasm** giving a way to achieve the priority of states, so I can sort it no matter by ruby or database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`aasm`](https://github.com/aasm/aasm) and other `state_machine` gems don't do anything other than provide a structure for your records. To the best of my knowledge, they don't have any way to prioritize the data (only a way to determine its `state`).

I would recommend looking at getting `ActiveRecord` to handle it (with [`order`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering)):

```
#app/models/your_model.rb
Class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :prioritize, -> { order(unpaid: :desc, paid: :asc) }
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
def index
    @items = Model.where(values: here).prioritize
end
```

--

Of course, the `order` method needs work, but I hope you get the idea? I can refactor if you want me to

Comment: Very thanks for you answer, it is clear and simple. But I think you know the type of **aasm_state** is string, so, it is hard to use them for a relatively complicated sort issue.

Comment: Why is it hard to sort with the type 'string'?